# Relationship between Qt framework and Nokia 's meego-harmattan

Tags: qt, jvm, nokia, maemo, meego

I am a beginner to Maemo Development. Has Nokia N9 come with JVM? Some forums are saying
that it will come with dalvik VM. Is it true? If I want to develop Applications for Nokia N9(meego), I have to install both Qt SDK and harmattan sdk from the [link](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/Introduction.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Maemo is the older version of Nokia's Linux mobile handset platform, which merged with Intel's Moblin to make MeeGo.

Things are bit confusing on the Nokia N9 because there are really two APIs:

- Nokia's Swipe (http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/MeeGo/)
- MeeGoTouch(http://meego.gitorious.org/meegotouch)

I would recommend the Nokia APIs as they specifically target that device and provide beginner friendly QML APIs.

The MeeGoTouch API is more for the MeeGo Tablet UX, but should also work if you prefer. It is completely open source, while Nokia's layer is proprietary.

The platform does not ship with a JVM. However, MeeGo is a Linux, so you can install anything you want - including a JVM - but that probably is not what you want in this case.

Comment: The MeeGo guys also say that Maemo 6 == Harmattan on this [link](http://wiki.meego.com/MeeGo_and_Maemo6) but Nokia has moved away from the Maemo name in favor of MeeGo.

Comment: The Qt SDK 1.1.2 [download link](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) contains the Harmattan simulator and libs. It is in the 'experimental' section so you need to run the SDK Updater (might be under the Help menu item) and then click over to Packages and select Harmattan under the 'experimental' section.

Comment: but why nokia has provided the separate http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/Introduction.html (SDK)? The New developer will be confused because of this..

Comment: @Mischa: In Qt SDK you can write Qt-based apps only. In Harmattan SDK you can use about 500 open-source libs (including Qt) and also platform specific APIs.

Comment: so Harmattan SDK is better than Qt SDK(installing from experimental).Harmattan SDK only is enough to develop ? am i right?

Comment: Each approach has different benefits: Qt SDK is simpler while Harmattan SDK enables more APIs. It really depends on your project and what your personal goals are, but either approach will enable you to build apps for the Nokia N9.